# How to create a new parent node outside the .ref(/path) in Firebase Realtime Database using Cloud Functions (Typescript)?

Tags: android, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

[image: Diagram of Database]

So basically I want my Cloud Functions to create a new parent node named "Civil" whenever there is a new node in "Agent".
Here is the code I tried:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

export const addCivilData = functions.database
.ref('/Agent/{AgentID}')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

    const userData = snapshot.val() 
    const newUsername = userData.username
    const defCivilStatus: string = "new"

    return snapshot.ref.parent?.child('Civil').child(`${newUsername}`).update(`${defCivilStatus}`)
})
```

The ? after parent is automatically generated by VSCODE and shows some rules on hovering the the mouse pointer.

[image: Rules shown]

and if I remove that "?" it gives red underline on `snapshot.ref.parent`.

I want to create a parent node "Civil" and child node with username as fetched and set its value to defCivilStatus.
please help

EDIT:
Additional Error screenshots

### [image: Logs]

### [image: used .set here]

[image: cmd error]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210666/discussion-on-question-by-dharmaraj-how-to-create-a-new-parent-node-outside-the).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.addCivilData = functions.database
.ref('/Agent/{AgentID}')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

 const userData = snapshot.val();
 console.log('userData', userData);
 const newUsername = userData.username;
 console.log('newUsername', newUsername);
 const defCivilStatus = "new";
         return snapshot.ref.parent.parent.child('Civil').child(`${newUsername}`).set(`${defCivilStatus}`);
});
```

And follow the firebase func. logs

Use the `!` symbol is the IDE shows any error on the line `return snapshot.ref....` like shown in the below code:

```
return snapshot.ref.parent!.parent!.child('Civil').child(`${newUsername}`).set(`${defCivilStatus}`);
```

Comment: I'll let you know the output soon. Busy atm. But can you explain how does this solve that parent issue in last line? I hope the parent isn't null. But is the issue tbh?

Comment: The problem is not ref.parent. Problem is update func. in this line. Update fails

Comment: I had a `console.log(" ")` before the return line. It worked but the return statement was error. So possibly the return statement was the error.

Comment: Can I use `exports const addCivilData` instead of `exports.addCivilData`??

Comment: there is no such use in documents

Comment: `Object is possibly 'null'` give me this error in VSCode

Comment: I still ran in and this is the error shown in the firebase console logs. `Error: Reference.update failed: First argument  must be an object containing the children to replace.` By the way, the console.log(" ") functions worked. Problem is in the return statement only.

Comment: which object is null. Probably username can be null. Did you check in log

Comment: [Screenshot of Firebase logs](https://imgur.com/9xqkbd4) Please have a look. And here is the screenshot of [VSCODE error](https://imgur.com/JtO3KPD)